# CSS: inline-block vs inline text

Tags: css

I want my block to be set by `line-height` (just like i do with text). As i know i should use `display: inline-block` in this case, but this doesn't work for me. Why?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="block">
    <div></div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    test
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.block {
    line-height: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.block div {
    height: 40px;
    width: 28px;
    background-color: #f0f;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5E7eP/)**

Comment: That is doing exactly what you told it to do, what is your expected outcome?

Comment: I want pink ".block div" to be centered in the middle of the main ".block". I don't want to use hacks for block-elements because i have to change the height of the text and the inline div in the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi now add your **div** `aertical-align middle` in your **css**

```
.block div {
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5E7eP/3/)***

-**-------------------------------------------**
now if you want to center this box than add `text-align center` as like this

```
.block {
    text-align: center;
}
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5E7eP/7/)***

Comment: vertical-align: middle; was the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you are trying to center the purple block vertical?

in that case your mixing thing up:

a `<div>` is a block-level element, where text is not. so if you say `line-height`, you specify text-alignment of the content for that element, not positioning of a block element, to solve the centering of that purple block, use padding or margin:

```
.block div {
    height: 40px;/* 50 - 40 = 10pixel/2 = 5px space */
    width: 28px;
    background-color: #f0f;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

[Demo over here jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5E7eP/5/)